# Simple Esper example in Java

Tags: java, esper

I downloaded the most recent Esper. I added the path to the root esper directory and the lib subdirectory to the `.bash_profile CLASSPATH`. I sourced the `bash_profile`.

I then entered this program that I found on the web but it gives me this error. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

> javac exampleMain.java exampleMain.java:1: error: package
>   com.espertech.esper.client does not exist

```
    import com.espertech.esper.client.*;



    import com.espertech.esper.client.*;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Date;

    public class exampleMain {

    public static class Tick {
        String symbol;
        Double price;
        Date timeStamp;

        public Tick(String s, double p, long t) {
            symbol = s;
            price = p;
            timeStamp = new Date(t);
        }
        public double getPrice() {return price;}
        public String getSymbol() {return symbol;}
        public Date getTimeStamp() {return timeStamp;}

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Price: " + price.toString() + " time: " + timeStamp.toString();
        }
    }

    private static Random generator = new Random();

    public static void GenerateRandomTick(EPRuntime cepRT) {

        double price = (double) generator.nextInt(10);
        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String symbol = "AAPL";
        Tick tick = new Tick(symbol, price, timeStamp);
        System.out.println("Sending tick:" + tick);
        cepRT.sendEvent(tick);

    }

    public static class CEPListener implements UpdateListener {

        public void update(EventBean[] newData, EventBean[] oldData) {
            System.out.println("Event received: " + newData[0].getUnderlying());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //The Configuration is meant only as an initialization-time object.
        Configuration cepConfig = new Configuration();
        cepConfig.addEventType("StockTick", Tick.class.getName());
        EPServiceProvider cep = EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider("myCEPEngine", cepConfig);
        EPRuntime cepRT = cep.getEPRuntime();

        EPAdministrator cepAdm = cep.getEPAdministrator();
        EPStatement cepStatement = cepAdm.createEPL("select * from " +
                "StockTick(symbol='AAPL').win:length(2) " +
                "having avg(price) > 6.0");

        cepStatement.addListener(new CEPListener());

       // We generate a few ticks...
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            GenerateRandomTick(cepRT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you even been able to `import` the package `com.espertech.esper.client.*` using your IDE?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I am doing this from the command line I don't have an ide. Although, I suppose I can download IntelliJ but I don't see how adding an extra level of indirection would help?

Comment: When I look at the downloaded directory, I don't see anything resembleing a com jar file.

Comment: If there are no jar/war files for `com`, then you can't import it or use it as a dependency.  Maybe there is something wrong with the Esper set up?  Do you have a pom.xml (or some other build related file) ?

Comment: I am beginning to believe that this has to do with maven. I don't understand how I am supposed to install esper because it seems as if just untar'ing adding the directory to the CLASSPATH, doesn't do the job. On the other hand the example programs work.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised it has to do with Maven...I've had my handful of issues related to builds since it can't update or reindex the `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the [esper-5.0.0.jar](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper/download/download.html) to your project workspace.If you face other problem to run the esper project, you may try this very simple & primitive tutorial ["Getting Started tutorial](http://coffeeonesugar.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/getting-started-with-esper-in-5-minutes/)".
 Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

No need to add the classpath at .bash_profile CLASSPATH. Simply add some missing jars to the build path.

Comment: Recommend as a comment